# Problem with ApiPlatform SearchFilter returning all results

Tags: api-platform.com

```
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"serial": "partial"})
```

I have the following on a products entity. The problem is, when I make API call with ?serial= it returns ALL items in the DB, obviously should have only returned one

EDIT:
This is caused by using a custom controller for the GET method. Looks like it needs refactorring.

```
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "controller"=DeviceGetCollectionController::class,
 *          },
```

Bypasses the searchFilter

Answer (score 0):

Solution was add a check in the custom controller:

```
    if($request->get('serial')){
        return $query->findBy(['company' => $user->getCompany(),'serial'=>$request->get('serial')]);
    }
```